# Accessing Format-Table output

Tags: powershell

I have something like this:

```
$outp = Get-Process | % {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        ID   = $_.Id
        ProcessName  = $_.ProcessName
    } 
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

which results in `$outp` like this:

```
  ID ProcessName
  -- -----------
6752 ApplicationFrameHost
8944 browser_broker
```

How do I access an individual row (or column for that matter) in `$outp`?

Comment: Do not use formatting cmdlets if you want to further process the data. `Format-*` should only ever be used for displaying data to a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use `$outp = get-process | select ID, Processname` like Ansgar said and than you can access it by using `$outp[row].ID`, like `$outp[0].ID` will be the ID of first entry.

If you need to display it, use `$outp | ft -autosize`.